# Activating Lite to pro version process

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I'm building Lite version for the Pro version App i have. The Lite version has some features 'blocked', not activated as the full pro version and a Purchase button
to purchase or upgrade to Pro.

What's no clear to me is when the user that has a Lite version buys the Pro version, which scenario actually happens, does he install a new Pro package to his iphone/ipad and the Lite version still exists there (until the user uninstall it if he chooses) or do I need to remove the Lite version limitations and have the same App behave like a Pro full featured version at this point?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right choice between your two suggestions really depends on if you are using in-app purchase or not.

**With** In-App Purchase you have to ship the full app with features disabled. The upgrade button would then trigger the in-app purchase. After successful purchase you would unlock the locked features programmatically.

**Without** In-App Purchase you would have two apps in the app store. The upgrade button in the light version would then send the user to the app store.

Comment: In-App is probably the best way to go. It makes a much better user experience to just hit a button and keep all settings, data, etc.

Comment: @Mundi which option is easier/faster With In-App or without. this is our first app and we anxious to have it out there after spending good effort on the app itself. If we select Without In-App do i need to do something other just created two versions and register it with the Apple store ? Thanks

Comment: @Mundi which option is easier/faster With In-App or without. this is our first app and we anxious to have it out there after spending good effort on the app itself. If we select Without In-App do i need to do something other just created two versions and register it with the Apple store ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to update to an other app (your pro version). The light version must include all features that the pro version does. But theu're disabled. Then the upgrade from the lite to the pro version just enables these features in the lite version. 
Then the lite version is the same as the pro.

Comment: Yes, that what i meant, including all features that the pro has but disabled. I guess this is the With in-App option which i need to read about. any step by step link link would be great